# RuntimeError: real is not implemented for tensors with non-complex dtypes

Tags: python, pytorch, speech-recognition, ctc

I have installed warpctc module. Then inside `home/sultan/Desktop/Adversarial-ASR-Attack/venv/lib/python3.8/sitepackages/art/estimators/speech_recognition/pytorch_deep_speech.py"` I have written the following code:

def magphase ( D, *, power= 1 ):
mag = torch.abs ( D)
zeros_to_ones = mag == 0
mag_nonzero = mag + zeros_to_ones
phase = torch.empty_like(D, dtype=torch.complex64)
phase.real = D.real / mag_nonzero + zeros_to_ones
phase.imag = D.imag / mag_nonzero
mag **= power
return mag, phase

But when I am calling this function `spectrogram, _ = magphase(transformed_input)`, I am getting following error:

```
 RuntimeError: real is not implemented for tensors with non-complex dtypes.
```

What can be probable solution? I am new to pytorch.